# Retrieve data from an endpoint

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology

Everyone,

One simple question : is it possible to retrieve the whole dataset (as a Turtle, or XML) of an endpoint ?

I've tried some things like download the whole data from a SPARQL query but the connection broke and if it doesn't break, the data isn't in a good format (and it's normal, it's results and not the original data). I tried in Python thank's to RDFlib and also thank's to a Linux tool, CUrl

I navigated around the web to find something interesting and I found out that : I need to download manually the data if the data is put (like on DBpedia with dumps). I also found some softwares that works but they cannot retrieve the whole data (they only retrieve a resource, like http://dbpedia.org/resource/*something*  ).

If it can be done, I'll be glad to ear that one. Indeed, if an endpoint is up-to-date, dumps aren't necessarily.

**EDIT :**

As an example, I can say that this command-line works : 
`curl -L -H "Accept:text/turtle" http://dbpedia.org/resource/Paris` works (at least on Linux distrib) ! **What I want** is that, but for the whole DBpedia datas. (and in my real-case example it's not dbpedia obviously, I don't want to download 20GB of datas !)

Clément

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [SPARQL Graph Store Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/). However, I think you'll find really large stores, like DBPedia, either wont provide an endpoint or will time out. Those dumps are there for a reason.

Comment: @chrisis You're right, but there I've a goal : download the whole data from an endpoint and that endpoint is storing a small amount of data. Do you have example of what I want to do ? Let's say my endpoint is `http://example.com/ep` :)

Comment: Please see my post Edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do, here in Python :

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper,TURTLE

query = "CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o } WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }"
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery(query)
sparql.setTimeout(0)
sparql.setReturnFormat(TURTLE)
results = sparql.query().convert()
#print(results)
file = open("output.ttl", "wb")
file.write(results)
file.flush()
file.close()
```

The limit isn't set and **it'll fail** there. Indeed DBpedia's endpoint is set to an execution timeout of 120 seconds. But if you find an endpoint with a timeout that suits you or without timeout, this piece of code works. It also works if you put a limit at the end of your SPARQL query, like `query = "CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o } WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 100"`

Comment: Note that this won't cover named graph information in the endpoint - it will only cover the default graph - which may or may not include all the triples in named graphs, depending on the endpoint configuration, but you'll lose the information about which triple was in which named graph.

Comment: You should **accept** your own answer such that we can assume the issue has been solved.

Comment: I'll be able to do it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for that information @JeenBroekstra . Do you have any ideas to counter that ?

Answer (score 0):

I am really new to SPARQL but **in theory** you can get all the triples from an endpoint using this query:

```
SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o . } 
LIMIT 100
```

I tried this in DBpedia https://dbpedia.org/sparql and it works, although you should use LIMIT to keep the results to a reasonable size (even if you don't use LIMIT, there is  an internal limit on the DBpedia endpoint to prevent overloading the server). In practice there could be millions of triples so probably only want to use this kind of query to better understand the data.

Comment: I've already tried that one. The problem is that the results doesn't come in a formatted syntax : indeed, let's say `?p` is `<http://example.org/property1>`, then the result will come as `subject1 http://example.org/property1 ?object1` (`<` & `>` are missing) . And there's much more than this, like string syntax (double quote), nodes, backslash, ...

Comment: Please see my post Edit

Comment: SPARQL v1.1 (the current version) allows choice of output in XML, CSV or tab separated value format, but I think this has to be configured in the program that calls the endpoint. I haven't figured out how to choose the output format in the DBpedia endpoint. It may also be possible to use string functions following the SELECT to remove unwanted elements, but this doesn't seem the best way.